# Assign Combine publisher to variables using the new SwiftUI Observable framework

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

SwiftUI 5 now uses the `@Observable` wrapper to observe changes in a class instead of conforming it to `ObservableObject`. This gets rid of `@Published` wrappers which I actively use in my workflow:

**Old implementation**

```
class OldObservable: ObservableObject {
    
    let model = SomeModel()
    
    @Published var someValue: String?
    
    init() {
        setupSubscribers()
    }
    
    func setupSubscribers() {
        // someValuePublisher could be PassthroughSubject<String?, Never>()
        model.someValuePublisher.assign(to:$someValue)
    }
}
```

**New implementation**

```
@Observable
class NewObservable {
    
    let model = SomeModel()
    
    var someValue: String?
    
    init() {
        setupSubscribers()
    }
    
    func setupSubscribers() {
        // Not working anymore
        model.someValuePublisher.assign(to:$someValue)
    }
}
```

Since someValue is not a published property, I can't use the usual `assign(to:)` anymore.

So far to make it work I have to use the old implementation assign(to:on) which I heard can lead to retain cycle issues and it's longer code for the same result.

```
    var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func setupSubscribers() {
        model.someValuePublisher.assign(to: \.self.someValue, on: self).store(in: &subscribers)
    }
```

I could also use the `sink(ReceivedValue:)` but it also lengthen the code.
So is there a new and concise way to bind Combine publishers to the new Observable framework?

Comment: A better example of why this is a breaking change is that you have, for example, two @Published properties in your model and one is assigned to the other with some computation in the middle (which is the basis of functional programming). IE. $someValue.map {$0.awesomeFilter}.assign(to: $filteredValue). That has nothing to do with anything except the model and is critical to any combine app. I hope Apple makes this a priority for WWDC24 but the way they move these days even with bugs is incredibly slow. So. I'll continue to use ObservableObject and not worry about the slight performance diff.