# How to build a Combine Pipeline using SwiftUI's new @Observable macro?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I'm curious, does anyone know how to build a Combine Pipeline using a class that is built using the `@Observable` macro? (This is related to, but broader than a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77237491) I just found.)

For instance, with the old methods (ie subclassing from `ObservableObject`), we could have done this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

private class WhiteSpaceTrimmer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var incomingText: String
    @Published var outgoingText: String
    
    init(initialText: String = "") {
        self.incomingText = initialText
        self.outgoingText = initialText
        
        $incomingText
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }
            .assign(to: &$outgoingText)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var trimmer = WhiteSpaceTrimmer(initialText: "  \tHello World  ")
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Input", text: $trimmer.incomingText)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            HStack {
                Text("Raw Input: \"\(trimmer.incomingText)\"")
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Cleaned Output: \"\(trimmer.outgoingText)\"")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with the `@Observable`, we can't use the `@Published` macro which would give us bindings that we could use to hook up to our Combine pipeline. The following code will not compile:

```swift
@Observable private class WhiteSpaceTrimmer {
    var incomingText: String
    var outgoingText: String
    
    init(initialText: String = "") {
        self.incomingText = initialText
        self.outgoingText = initialText
        
        $incomingText
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }
            .assign(to: &$outgoingText)
    }
}
```

The error we get is `Cannot find '$incomingText' in scope` and `Cannot find '$outgoingText' in scope`, in addition to some secondary errors. If I try to use `@Bindable` before `var incomingText: String` to define `$incomingText`, I get the error message `'init(wrappedValue:)' is unavailable: The wrapped value must be an object that conforms to Observable`.

So, the question is, "is there a way of wiring up a Combine pipeline to the properties of an @Observable object, and if not, what alternative pattern should I use?"

If there isn't a better suggestion, I will continue to use `ObservableObject` subclasses for such scenarios. Some of the newer state-change optimisations will not be available, but that might be the better choice so long as the old ways are not deprecated.

Comment: The "old ways" are not deprecated. If you need a publisher, use `ObservableObject`.

Comment: That link has the only approach  so far.

Answer (score 1):

That first example is not valid SwiftUI, the processing should be done in a computed property passed into the subview, e.g. something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var incomingText = "  \tHello World  "
 
    var outgoingText: String {
        incomingText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TextField("Input", text: $incomingText)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            HStack {
                Text("Raw Input: \"\(incomingText)\"")
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Cleaned Output: \"\outgoingText)\"")
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is because SwiftUI already has a debounce built-in and it already has change tracking of state built-in. After multiple changes to `incomingText` have finished, the next event is a call to `body` which in turn calls `outgoingText` which runs the trimming. So there is no need for a Combine pipeline at all. That `WhiteSpaceTrimmer` `ObservableObject` has essentially reimplemented what SwiftUI already does.

To try to port it to `@Observable` is another mistake because that is for a model, not for a controller like a text trimmer. If trimming was a long running background task it would be implemented in `.task(id: incomingText)` using async/await and assign the result to another `@State var`. If you want to simulate a long task you can put a sleep before it which will be cancelled via an exception whenever the `id` param changes, e.g.

```
@State var outgoingText = ""

.task(id: incomingText) {
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.1))
        outgoingText = incomingText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    }
    catch {
        // cancelled because incoming text changed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There's a lot of great info there. The example was intended to show values being fed from a SwiftUI View into a Combine pipeline that persists in a State object and which feeds results back into the view. So the specifics of the small example didn't concern me, but may have been poorly chosen. Sorry! Nonetheless, I did not know that SwiftUI has debounce built into it. That's great to know! Also, I do like the alternate way you've suggested I organise things. I'll play around with these ideas a bit. Much Gratitude!